# Ui resizes when leaving immersive mode

Tags: android

I am currently playing around with the new immersive mode for KitKat and have ran into the following bug.  When I switch from an activity in immersive mode to one not in immersive mode, the screen will readjust, as if the second activity was originally being created in full screen, then resizing.  I've tried leaving immersive mode onPause and even before finishing the immersive class, but this still happens.  Any ideas?